# List comprehension and lambdas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, list-comprehension

I wanted to create a list of lambdas, but it didn't quite work out as I hoped.

```
L = [(lambda x: x/y) for y in range(10)]
```

I expected every function in the list to divide its argument by its index, but all functions only divide by the last index.

```
>>> L[1](5)
0.5555555555555556
>>> L[5](5)
0.5555555555555556
>>> 5/9
0.5555555555555556
```

Is this kind of list comprehension, where every lambda has its own copy of `y`possible in Python?

Comment: There is only one `y` in your code, and after you create your list, `y` has the value 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `y` in your lambda refers to the last value that `y` had in the scope it came from, i.e., 9.

The easiest way to get the behavior you want is to use a default argument in your lambda:

```
lambda x, y=y: x/y
```

This captures the value of `y` at the moment the lambda function is defined.

You can also do a "double-lambda", calling a function that *returns* the lambda you want, passing in the desired value of `y`:

```
(lambda y: lambda x: x/y)(y)
```

Here, the outer lambda provides a new scope each time you call it.

Comment: Capturing with default argument is very elegant! Much nicer than having to create an outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need the loop and the lambda to be in different scopes.

```
def make_divider(y):
    return lambda x: x / y

L = [make_divider(y) for y in range(10)]

print(L[2](5) == 5 / 2)
print(L[4](5) == 5 / 4)
```

Comment: That is a very concise and elegant way of stating what must be done.